# Can fire music work with the flame dancer archtype?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, bard, archetype

I'm interested in picking up [Fire Music](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/ultimateMagicFeats.html#fire-music) for a Flame Dancer, which gets Burning hands, Flaming Sphere, and Fireball at level 8. However the way Fire Music's prerequisite line is worded confuses me:

> Prerequisites: Spellcraft 5 ranks, ability to cast bard spells, **ability to cast an arcane fire spell from some other spellcasting class.**

Do you just need to be able to cast a spell that the bard normally isn't able to? Or do you need to be multi-classed to use this feat?

Answer (score 7):

No.

The flame dancer archetype adds *burning hands*, *flaming sphere*, and *fireball* to your bard spells known. You still cast them as bard spells, so you do not have “some other spellcasting class” that has the “ability to cast an arcane fire spell.” You have the same class, bard, able to do that (and, to be sure, bards have fire spells of their own that they could learn, so this isn’t even necessarily a case unique to flame dancers).

Note also that these are still “bard spells” for you. Fire Music doesn’t use that wording, which is a good thing, but if you see things referring to “bard spells,” that includes those spells (for you). They are not wizard spells for you, because you are not a wizard, do not have them in a wizard spellbook, and are not casting them with wizard spell slots. Spells do not have a “native” class associated with them; they just are “of” whatever class you are using to cast them.

Finally, please note that Fire Music is an *awful* feat. Fire damage is one of the weakest in the game (very commonly resisted), so swapping damage *to* it is usually the opposite of what you want to do. The trick with summoned creatures is a much better application, but of course bards are not generally superb summoners and really, “better” here does not mean “good.” And the cost of entry here is immense, requiring multiclassing among spellcasting classes and then burning a feat. There may be good reasons to take the feat despite all this, but you should do so with care and aware of the problems.

Answer (score 2):

### As written, you need to be multi-classed.

More precisely, you need to:

- be able to cast bard spells, so you need at least one level in Bard (or Skald)
- be able to cast an arcane fire spell from some other spellcasting class, so you need levels in an other arcane spellcasting class so you can cast at least one fire spell with this other class (not bard). The fire spell can also be on the Bard spell list, but you need to have an other class able to cast it to work as a prerequisite for the feat. It is unclear what exactly is gathered behind "spellcasting class". Would a rogue with the Minor Magic(spark) Talent count? That's difficult to know.

Anyway I highly recommend you to houserule this prerequisite. Just remove the "from some other spellcasting class" part and you will get a less terrible feat, still not terrific but at least it *could* be used.

Comment: I know this answer has nearly the same content as KRyan's, but I think the way of explaining is different enough to be worth the redundancy.